# Extending EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in jasypt

Tags: java, properties, jasypt

I am currently using jasypt in my application and it works great the way it is set up.

However, the password is set as an instance variable in the class which makes it available to thread dumps and generally lives in the session. I would like to make the password available only when required.

For this, I thought extending EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, to provide access to the properties programatically, would be the best bet. However the class is a final class and cannot be subclassed. How would I achieve access to the properties programatically in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution assuming you are providing an Encryptor to the EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Provide the password to the encryptor config instead of setting as an instance variable in the class.

```
<spring:bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <spring:constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
  <spring:property name="location" value="myapp.properties" />
</spring:bean> 

<spring:bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
  <spring:property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
  <spring:property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
  <spring:property name="passwordEnvName" value="JASYPT_PSWD_ENV" />      
</spring:bean>
```

By this the password is only available with the encryptor and it is used only when required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks user1760178. So, if I am understanding this correctly, the JASYPT_PSWD_ENV will be an encrypted environment variable? and this is the database password that I want to encrypt, correct?

Comment: You got it half correct. The JASYPT_PSWD_ENV is anenvironment variable. But this environmental variable is the password(KEY) with used to encrypt your database password. The encrypted database password is stored in the properties file. This JASYPT_PSWD_ENV as environment varaible is used by the Jasypt encryptor to decrypt the encrypted database password from the properties file and provide it to the class which needs the database password.

Comment: Hmm... I am lost !

How would this avoid having the database password in the singleton bean?
I was hoping to populate the database password in my class as a local variable in a method, so that the scope is reduced. I am unsure how that can be achieved.

Comment: Hi All, Could anyone please guide for this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9610764... Thanks, Sony